# JavaFX StackPane/group prevents me from resizing screen

Tags: javafx, resize, stackpanel

I cant get this to resize, it always go for the preferred size for each screen. This is not ideal for a full screen application. It bascially just becomes a little box in the top left corner =(

I've spent days on this now but cant get it to work.

Could anyone tell me what im doing wrong? thanks

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static final String MAIN_SCREEN = "main"; 
public static final String MAIN_SCREEN_FXML = "../gui/main.fxml"; 
public static final String CUSTOMER_SCREEN = "customer_main"; 
public static final String CUSTOMER_SCREEN_FXML = "../gui/customer_main.fxml"; 





@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    ScreensController mainContainer = new ScreensController();      
       mainContainer.loadScreen(Main.MAIN_SCREEN, 
                            Main.MAIN_SCREEN_FXML); 
       mainContainer.loadScreen(Main.CUSTOMER_SCREEN, 
               Main.CUSTOMER_SCREEN_FXML); 
       mainContainer.setScreen(Main.MAIN_SCREEN); 
       Group root = new Group(); 

       root.getChildren().addAll(mainContainer); 
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
       primaryStage.show(); 
       mainContainer.requestLayout();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

First screen controller class (has FXML file):

```
public class MainScreenController implements ControlledScreen, Initializable{

ScreensController myController;

@FXML
private VBox mainScreen;


@FXML
private void mainScreenClicked(){
    myController.setScreen(Main.CUSTOMER_SCREEN);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

}

@Override
public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {       
    myController = screenParent; 
}
```

Stack pane for a nice layout:

```
    public class ScreensController extends StackPane {

    public ScreensController(){

    }


    private HashMap<String, Node> screens = new HashMap<>();

     public void addScreen(String name, Node screen) { 
           screens.put(name, screen); 
       } 

     public boolean loadScreen(String name, String resource) { 
         try { 
           FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));   
           Parent loadScreen = (Parent) myLoader.load();
           ControlledScreen myScreenControler = 
                  ((ControlledScreen) myLoader.getController()); 

           myScreenControler.setScreenParent(this); 
           addScreen(name, loadScreen); 
           return true;

         }catch(Exception e) { 
           System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
           e.printStackTrace();
           return false; 
         } 
       } 

     public boolean setScreen(final String name) { 

         if(screens.get(name) != null) { //screen loaded 
           final DoubleProperty opacity = opacityProperty(); 
           //Is there is more than one screen 

           if(!getChildren().isEmpty()){ 
             Timeline fade = new Timeline( 
               new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                            new KeyValue(opacity,1.0)), 
               new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000), 

                   new EventHandler() { 

                     @Override 
                     public void handle(Event t) { 
                       //remove displayed screen 
                       getChildren().remove(0); 
                       //add new screen 
                       getChildren().add(0, screens.get(name)); 
                       Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline( 
                           new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                                  new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)), 
                           new KeyFrame(new Duration(800), 
                                  new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0))); 
                       fadeIn.play(); 
                     }


                   }, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0))); 
             fade.play(); 
           } else { 
             //no one else been displayed, then just show 
             setOpacity(0.0); 
             getChildren().add(screens.get(name)); 
             Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline( 
                 new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                              new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)), 
                 new KeyFrame(new Duration(2500), 
                              new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0))); 
             fadeIn.play(); 
           } 
           return true; 
         } else { 
             System.out.println("screen hasn't been loaded!\n"); 
             return false; 
       } 
}
     public boolean unloadScreen(String name) { 
         if(screens.remove(name) == null) { 
           System.out.println("Screen didn't exist"); 
           return false; 
         } else { 
           return true; 
         } 
       }
```

}

interface so that each screen knows its parent:

```
    public interface ControlledScreen {

public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenPage);
}
```

Second controller class to verify that the stackpane works (has FXML file):

```
public class CustomerMenuController implements ControlledScreen, Initializable {


    ScreensController myController;
    @FXML 
    private FlowPane customerMenuFlow;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3;i++){
            new Customer();
        }
        Button [] menuButtons = new Button[Customer.customers.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < Customer.customers.size();i++){
            menuButtons[i] = new Button("Customer " + i);

            customerMenuFlow.getChildren().add(menuButtons[i]);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {
        myController = screenParent; 
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);` for resizable applications. Not in this context anyway. Once you remove that line, the application will start with its preferred size, but then the user is able to drag the corners of the window to resize the application.